# How to set input parameter in a procedure where there is IN FUNCTION?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRODUCT
(
  IN products varchar(64)
) 
BEGIN 
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 a
   WHERE a.list in products; 
END; 

CALL PRODUCT('A');
```

**Goal & Try**

- In `PRODUCT` procedure, it's ok when parameter is one(`CALL PRODUCT('A')` ). But when input is multiple like `('A','B','C','D')`, it could not solve.
- The index can be used. The `list` field is an index.

Comment: ('A','B','C','D') on input is seen as 4 input variables - you need to supply these as 1 variable and manipulate them in the sp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` function.

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.list,products)>0;
```

Then call your procedure like below.

```
call PRODUCT('A,B,C,D');
```

If you have index on `a.list` you can try below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRODUCT
(
  IN products varchar(64)
) 
BEGIN 
  SET @sql = concat('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 a WHERE a.list in(','''',REPLACE(products,',',''','''),'''',')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;   
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
END;
```

Comment: the problem is that index could not be used when using FIND_IN_SET

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it. @Jack

Comment: There are a number of errors in the code including sql is not declared the sql = statement is not terminated, @sql is not the same as sql,you need a SET clause to assign a value to a variable and there is no evidence of delimiters being set

Comment: Edited. @P.Salmon

Comment: given call product('a,b,c,d') this will @sql will be SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 a WHERE a.list in(a,b,c,d) ; - which will throw an unknown column error.

Comment: Edited. @P.Salmon